# .net5 with Ajax call

Tags: datatables, .net-5

I tried to call action in the controller using Ajax call. The call is work fine, but in the same action I have data table and I got error on the code
var draw = HttpContext.Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault(); and the error is incorrect content-type application/json charset=utf-8.

this is my ajax call

```
    $(function () {
    $.ajax({
      
       url: "@Url.Action("get_600UpdateFailuer", "_600PermitFailuer")",
       // url: '/_600PermitFailuer/get_600UpdateFailuer', 
         type: "GET",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
         success: function(res) {
    window.location.href = url;
           },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });

});
```

and this is my controller

```
public JsonResult get_600UpdateFailuer()
    {
        //var TransactionLogId = Request.Cookies["TransactionLogId"];
        var InstructorId = Request.Cookies["InstructorId"];
        try
        {

            var draw = HttpContext.Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();   
            var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault() +
                                          "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDirection = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();
            var searchValue = Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault();
            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
            int recordsTotal = 0;


            var classData = (from T in _db1.TransactionLogs
                                 //where C.MonitorId == InstructorId
                             select new TransactionLog
                             {
                                 TransDesc = T.TransDesc,
                                 TransType = T.TransType,
                                 TransDateTime = T.TransDateTime
                             }).ToArray().AsQueryable();  // This will return IQueryable<T>

            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn)))
            {
                classData = classData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDirection);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
            {
                classData = classData.Where(m => m.TransDesc != null && m.TransDesc.ToLower().Contains(searchValue)
                                            || m.TransType != null && m.TransType.Contains(searchValue));
            }

            recordsTotal = classData.Count();
            var data = classData.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            var jsonData = new
            {
                //draw = draw,
                recordsFiltered = recordsTotal,
                recordsTotal = recordsTotal,
                data = data
            };
            return Json(jsonData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For starters, what do you expect `HttpContext.Request.Form` to contain?  The data you're sending is an empty object: `data: '{}'`  And it's being sent on the query string, not in a form (since this is a GET request).

Comment: As an aside, this seems like a bad idea: `throw ex.InnerException;`  What if there is no inner exception?  Or what if the caught exception contains important information about the problem?   If you want the exception to continue out of this method, just remove the try/catch entirely and let the exception bubble up the stack.  But explicitly ignoring parts of the exception certainly won't make debugging any easier.

Comment: I'm using datatable with .net 5. so I have to use HttpContext.Request.Form to draw my table.

Comment: But don't you still have to actually send that data to the server?  Regardless of what "datatable" is or what .Net 5 does, the jQuery code shown isn't sending any data in the HTTP request.  So if the server-side code is *expecting* data in the HTTP request then it won't find any.

Comment: I don't need to sent any data. just have ajax call to call my view and from the view I called a data from database and show it in datable. so do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: I used the similar method and its work fine but is not called from ajax. only I got this error if the called from Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.form) for `Request.Form`:

> The Form property is populated when the HTTP request Content-Type value is either "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "multipart/form-data".

But the content type you're using is:

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

So you *could* update your `contentType` to use something that is compatible with `Request.Form`, and probably use a `POST` request instead of `GET`.  Or, even better, don't use `Request.Form` at all and instead let the framework's model binding work for you and have the controller action method accept a parameter of the type you're looking for.  (Which you may need to explicitly create.)

For example, if you were to send an object like this to the server:

```
data: {
  someProperty: 123,
  anotherProperty: 'this is a test'
}
```

Then in your server-side code you might define a class like this:

```
public class MyRequestDTO
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Which your method would accept as a parameter:

```
public JsonResult get_600UpdateFailuer(MyRequestDTO input)
```

Then within that method you should have the populated object.  Whatever the more complex shape of the object *you* need happens to be, you may need to reverse-engineer the tool you're using and observe the shape of the data it sends to the server.  Your browser's debugging tools will be very helpful in that regard.

---

***However...***

Despite your [assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992312/net5-with-ajax-call?noredirect=1#comment125499706_70992312) [to the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992312/net5-with-ajax-call?noredirect=1#comment125499786_70992312) [contrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992312/net5-with-ajax-call?noredirect=1#comment125499803_70992312), in order to complete the implementation of your functionality you are still going to have to send data to the server.  Currently your AJAX request sends an empty object:

```
data: '{}'
```

An empty object will contain *none* of the values you're looking for in the server-side code.

Comment: var draw = Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();  I should use that in .net5 to built the datable for you.. it's a required

Comment: Every time when I hit the line    var draw = Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault(); 
 I got the error Incorrect Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'. I changed the    contentType: "multipart/form-data", and still have same error.

Comment: @LuayAlmamury: Try leaving out the `contentType` property in your AJAX request object entirely.  According to [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) the default value is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`.  Also check the AJAX request in the network tab of your browser's debugging tools to observe what the actual `contentType` is that is being sent to the server.  But again, if you're using MVC or WebAPI (which are kind of merged at this point anyway) then you really shouldn't be using `Request.Form` and should rely on model binding instead.

Comment: David, how I can rely on model binding instead ? can you give me some example please.

Comment: @LuayAlmamury: It depends on the shape of the request going to the server.  The [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) provides information on the shape of that object, which is more complex than a couple of properties.  But you're also going to need to *actually send* that object to the server, which you're currently not doing.  Once you do that you can also use your browser's debugging tools to reverse-engineed the shape of that object to better determine what your C# class needs to look like.  I'd recommend starting with just one property and then add more.